# memcheck-amd64- killed by OOM

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm using Valgrind to correct a segmentation fault in my code, but when the run arrives to the segmentation fault point my process is killed.

Searching in /var/log/syslog file, I can see that the process `memcheck-amd64-` (valgrind?) has been killed:

```
Sep  7 12:48:34 fabiano-HP kernel: [10154.654505] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-c2.scope,task=memcheck-amd64-,pid=3688,uid=1000
Sep  7 12:48:34 fabiano-HP kernel: [10154.654560] Out of memory: Killed process 3688 (memcheck-amd64-) total-vm:11539708kB, anon-rss:6503332kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:12952kB oom_score_adj:0
Sep  7 12:46:26 fabiano-HP org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Cache1[3661]: message repeated 3 times: [ libpng error: Read Error]
Sep  7 12:48:34 fabiano-HP systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
```

Now, the problem is that Valgrind doesn't write the output file, so I can't understand what's going on... how can I avoid this? I mean, what's happening?

EDIT:
I'm running Valgrind with this command `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes  --log-file=valgrind-out.txt ./mainCPU -ellpack`

Comment: If you have a segmentation violation without valgrind, then you might have an idea of the origin of the problem by using a debugger such as gdb and look at the stacktrace when the segfault happens, check if the stack is still in a valid state, etc ...
 Note that if the bug that causes a segfault is also the culprit for the huge memory increase leading to the OOM, then typically valgrind will (should) report an error before the OOM intervenes (because the memory increase should happen after the error being reported).

Comment: Also, valgrind starts to write the output file at the beginning of the execution. So  can you clarify what you see in valgrind-out.txt ? Do you find this file ?
Note that sending manually a signal 11 to valgrind leads to a correct indication in the output file that the process was terminated with signal 11.

Comment: @phd valgrind-out.txt content was not usefull to debug, but i found the problem: i was having overflow when i computed the indeces. using unsigned long long i solved that problem

Comment: Run without the options first (keep the logfile). This should use less memory. Then if errors are detected add the appropriate options and run again.

Comment: @fabianod good that you found the origin of your problem. Strange that the overflow problem creates a signal or whatever  that leads to valgrind not producing clear error messages. Valgrind is supposed to handle all signals (except kill -9) and produce an output. Do you have a small reproducer ? You can then file a valgrind bug.